# Really Bizarre Google Fonts and Letter Space Issue that materialized out of thin air, foreign characters won't load

Tags: css, internationalization, webkit, rendering, webfonts

So, in the last few hours, my website in development sprouted an issue. Where there are the character İ or I in small-caps variant, loading Roboto from google fonts, the spacing is suddenly all messed up in Chrome and Safari. I looked through all code and reverted many changes to no avail, and it is fine in Firefox.
Again, It was fine a few hours ago and I really cannot figure out what is going on, you can see it at the last menu item, or the first header in the third block of the website (dark grey) where it says tebli̇ğ çağris (it pastes this weirdo character instead of the i). I know I have a string replacing script in there that might look suspicious, but it happens with it removed as well..
http://goo.gl/pk38u

I have debugged a little more and what seems to be happening is that the browser, in lowercasing İ, makes it into a garbled i with two dots, one misbehaving in most browsers, but I don't understand how it came up now and not before, and what change caused this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Looks normal here (Chrome 26). Note that Google is pushing out updates tonight (Chrome 27), maybe you got caught in the middle of one?

Comment: I'm on Mac by the way, as I said, safari too, so I don't think it is an update problem.

Comment: The letter renders differently in Chrome25 than in Firefox21 (both in Linux), but I'm not seeing any so-called "weirdo characters".

Comment: That is strange, I only have two macs on hand at the moment. Let me load up a vm to see what windows does.  I tested the default android browser and that made tags that contained the letter drop the font and show all lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Chrome 28 beta, the page indeed looks odd, and the issue can be reduced to the following simple case:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title></title>
<style>
body { text-transform: lowercase; font-variant: small-caps; }
</style>
Takvİm
```

Instead of the expected rendering in (fake) small-caps, the content appears as “takvim” in Chrome. And if letter spacing is added (say `letter-spacing: 1em` to see the effect clearly), one can see that “i” is really dotless i, “ı”, combined with a separate dot.

It’s bizarre indeed, and seems to happen when the data contains a dotted capital I, “İ”. On the page mentioned, a script converts some texts so that such letters are generated. For some reason, Chrome cannot handle content with that letter when it is asked to convert to lower case and to use small caps – and it does not fail just for that letter but for an entire element containing it.

To circumvent the problem, replace `text-transform: lowercase; font-variant: small-caps` by `text-transform: uppercase` and make the font size smaller so that you get the letters in desired size.

It is hardly ever useful to use `font-variant: small-caps`, since browsers implement it by using uppercase letters in reduced size, instead of proper small caps glyphs. (This isn’t what *should* happen, but it’s what actually happens in current browsers.) So you can just as well use uppercase and reduce the font size yourself, giving you better control – and avoiding this bizarre bug.

Comment: It seems that I will have to revert to that, I guess I can change it in the future if we are ever given true small caps. Thanks for confirming the issue.

Comment: To use true small caps, you would need to use `font-feature-settings` (with vendor prefixes). Oddly enough, although Roboto contains small caps, `font-feature-settings: "smcp"` does not work for it, even when testing with Roboto as a locally installed font (and using browsers that support the setting for other fonts containing small caps, such as Calibri). This might be a font format issue.